# CUDA: Why is there a benefit to having more than 8 threads per block?

Tags: cuda

I am a mathematician using CUDA for some numerical integration.   My understanding is that each Nvidia streaming multiprocessor has 8 CUDA cores.   So to me it seems that there is no benefit to using more than 8 threads per block.   However, when I run my code I get huge performance gain by using 32 threads per block as opposed to 8 threads per block.

Also I noticed there is huge gain using more than 12 blocks ( even though my  card only has 12 streaming multiprocessors).

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I think you need to read about the concept of warps in the CUDA programming guide. The CUDA execution model works like an SIMD architecture, and the width is 32 threads ("a warp"). Each multiprocessor has a lot of pipeline and memory latency and needs a large number of concurrent warps to hide that latency and achieve peak throughput. Again, all discussed in detail in the programming guide.

Comment: talonmies explained it very clearly. I just want to add one thing that usually the best blocks size should be a multiple of 64 to avoid register memory bank conflicts. A least this is true for CUDA old version. I am not sure if the register memory bank conflicts are still the problem for latest CUDA version.

Comment: As a side note, only sm_1x SMs had 8 Cuda Cores.  sm_2x (Fermi) SMs have 32 Cuda cores, and sm_3x (Kepler) SMX has 192 Cuda cores. Also, you will probably get even more benefit from using at least 64 threads per block, because you are limited to 8 blocks per SM on your hardware, so using 32 thread blocks is probably limiting occupancy.

Comment: Register allocation and instruction scheduling is done at warp granularity. Issuing instructions with less than WARP_SIZE threads active in general will result in no performance gains. Memory instructions may see improved performance as 8 threads will likely reference less cache lines than 32 threads resulting in less transactions per instruction. CUDA cores only refer to one type of execution unit in the SM. The Fermi and Kepler whitepapers mention other execution units.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

talonmies and chaohuang provide good information in the comments, and you should look into that (not sure why these aren't answers, but that's their call). In any event, I will provide an abbreviated partial answer to explain something that you might not be considering.

Let's say that you have 8 threads of control, and 8 processors. If all the instructions in all 8 threads are on-chip instructions taking only a single cycle, then all 8 threads will finish in `n` cycles (assuming `n` total instructions per thread).

Now let's say that each thread of control consists of `n` instructions, where a fraction `r` of these are off-chip memory instructions, which take, e.g., 100 cycles to complete. These 8 threads will now take `[(1 - r) + 100r]n` cycles to complete. If `r=0.1`, this is about 11 times more than the previous case.

Now let's say that we have 16 threads. When the first batch of 8 threads is blocked on the slow operations, the other threads can execute; on-chip instructions can execute, and off-chip instructions can start. So instead of needing `2[(1 - r) + 100r]n` cycles to complete all threads, you might need only a little more than `[(1 - r) + 100r]n`. In essence, because you have some room to overlap waiting threads with other threads, you can add more threads for free.

This is the great strength of the GPU model: massive parallelism to overcome long latency. It takes a long time to do a little bit of work, but not much more time to do a lot more work. Note that occupancy - related to the amount of work (in threads) you have ready to hide latency - isn't all that important for peak performance when the arithmetic intensity (related to `r` in the above formulae) is high. You might play around with the CUDA Occupancy Calculator to see the effect I descibe for different scenarios.

Comment: +1. Two comments: First, what @Patrick87 describes is commonly known as "latency hiding". Second, the occupancy calculator will tell you nothing about run time. Higher occupancy does not necessarily equate to higher performance, but it is a decent measure of latency hiding capacity.

Comment: @harrism Good point about occupancy not being about performance. I tried to get that across, but I think I might have been a little confusing about it.

Comment: Not your fault: occupancy is an unfortunately confusing metric. It is about performance, it's just not a direct relationship.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is latency hiding.

If you only have as many units of work (threads & blocks) as you have cores to work on them and execution hits a memory operation that needs hundreds of clock cycles to complete, the GPU has nothing else to work on so the cores sit idle until the memory op completes. That's wasting compute cycles.

If you offer more units of work than you have cores to do the work, then when one of the units of work hits a long-latency memory operation, the hardware scheduler can swap some other unit of work into the core(s) so that the cores are kept busy doing productive work while the long-latency memory operation completes. Having an excess of threads or blocks provides a better opportunity to use all the compute cycles when there are long-latency memory ops in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 2 ways to memory latency hiding in GPU:

1. increase in occupancy, which means have more threads than required to hide memory latency.
2. increase in independent operations per thread. This occupy those cores with the required parallelism.

Consider this sequence of computer instructions to compute large number of elements.

```
a = b + c;
d = a + c;
```

Second instruction will stall as it is waiting for result from first instruction to complete.

When you use only 8 threads, these threads are waiting and the GPU cores are idling.
However, if you have more threads, the GPU is able to schedule other elements' computations to be computed while the current warp is waiting. That is why when you increase the number of threads, it perform better. It is utilizing the CPU cores more efficiently =)

Hope this helps~